# Dataframe gets cut before an empty row in an excelfile

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I have an excel file which has 79 rows and 12 columns.

The problem I have is that when I run the following code, I only get 8 rows and 1 column.
Row 9, is an empty row, and I think this is the problem. But I don't know how to get by this problem. I have tried using `missing`, `ismissing`, `allowmissing` and `dropmissing` in different ways. But nothing I've tried has worked for me.

```
using DataFrames, XLSX
df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("file.xlsx")...)
println(df)
```

Is the empty row a problem, and how can I handle that empty row? Or is there something else that might cause the problem that I only get 8 rows and 1 column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [XLSX.jl documentation](https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/api/#XLSX.readtable):

> `stop_in_empty_row` is a boolean indicating wether an empty row marks the end of the
> table. If `stop_in_empty_row=false`, the TableRowIterator will continue to fetch rows
> until there's no more rows in the Worksheet. The default behavior is `stop_in_empty_row=true`.

so set `stop_in_empty_row=false` to read in empty rows as `missing`